# Как в Mockito проверить что метод не был вызван?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Для того чтобы проверить что метод был вызван мы вызываем `verify(mock).method()`. А как проверить обратное, что метод вызван **не** был?

Comment: Возможно, отрицанием результата первой проверки? `! verify(mock).method()` или как-то так.

Comment: @Nick Volynkin нет так не работает это void конструкция.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Использование метода `verify` в Mockito (из [документации](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.8.47/org/mockito/Mockito.html#4)):

```
LinkedList mockedList = mock(LinkedList.class);
mockedList.add("once");

mockedList.add("twice");
mockedList.add("twice");

mockedList.add("three times");
mockedList.add("three times");
mockedList.add("three times");
```

Чтобы удостоверится что метод был вызван один раз

```
verify(mockedList).add("once");
```

или

```
verify(mockedList, times(1)).add("once");
```

Оба варианта идентичны так как:

```
public static <T> T verify(T mock) {
    return MOCKITO_CORE.verify(mock, times(1));
}
```

Для вашего случая подойдут варианты:

```
verify(mockedList, times(0)).add("never happened");
verify(mockedList, never()).add("never happened");
```

[java](/questions/tagged/java)[junit](/questions/tagged/junit)[mockito](/questions/tagged/mockito)

Comment: Вариант с `never()`выглядит более красивым.

Comment: @temq Вы правы. Как же я забыл про него!?

Comment: @Asad Ganiev  а что в `verify(mockedList, atLeastOnce()).add("three times");`  делает часть `.add("three times")`?

Comment: @Pavel я их просто в добавок написал. Давайте я их убери чтобы не создавали путаницу.

Comment: @Asad Ganiev Спасибо за развернутый ответ и примеры подскажите еще что делает в `verify(mockedList, never()).add("never happened");` метод `.add("never happened");`? Для чего полезный метод add?

Comment: @Pavel На самом деле `add("never happened")` это метод `mockedList`а. Тут `mockedList.add("never happened");` верифицируется

Comment: @Asad Ganiev тоесть `"never happened"` это тот объект который не должен быть добавлен в список?

Comment: @Pavel Нет, я добавил подготовку `mock`ов ответ, взгляните и вы догадаетесь.